# OpenGL ES reading float value with glReadPixels()

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es

I know that there are a lot of questions concerning reading floats out of the buffer with glReadPixels(). But I still do not found an answer to my problem. 
I want to run this program an my iPhone. I am working with QT and tested the application first on the computer, and there it was no problem to read float values out of the buffer. But now with OpenGL ES I am not allowed to. My results are arbitrary.

What I wanted to change is. That I read GLubyte out of the buffer with glReadPixels() and cast these result to a float. 
Now to my question, why I am still getting arbitrary results? I have no clue if I am somehow reading the buffer wrong or if I am not able to cast GLubyte to float.

As I understand GLubyte is a simple unsigned char and as I know it should actually be no problem with a typecast to a float.

```
    glViewport(0, 0, _frameSize, _frameSize);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _fbo);
    glClearColor(1.0,0.0,0.0, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    program.bind();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat)*3, (GLvoid*)0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program.programId(), "texture"), 0);

    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

This is my draw call to the Framebuffer '_fbo'. As we can see I commended out the actual draw call, I just want to clear the buffer and hope to read out only the values (1,0,0).

```
    GLubyte* pixels = new GLubyte[_frameSize* _frameSize*3];
    float* pixels_f = new float[_frameSize* _frameSize*3];
    glReadPixels(0, 0, _frameSize, _frameSize, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

I am allocating ne storage and I want to read now the pixel values stored in the buffer.
And after that I only want to copy the values stored in 'pixels' to 'pixels_f' by casting them to a float.

My results are really arbitrary And I have no clue if it is because the cast from GLubyte to float does not work or if I am doing now something wrong by reading the buffer. Because as I worked with OpenGL on the computer and used GL_Float to read the buffer I had no problems with that.

---

After some more debugging I found out, that the glReadPixels() trows the error: 1280. But only by running on OpenGL ES and not with OpenGL.

When I run the program with OpenGL I have the version: GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION: 1.20

And with OpenGL ES:
GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00

I do not know why, actually both should be 1.2. I do not now if the version does any problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem. I am only allowed to load the type GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE with GL_RGBA. So :

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, _frameSize, _frameSize, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

now works.